# Is it square check

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write function to check if the argument is square of integer:

```
isSquare :: Int -> Bool
isSquare x = truncate(sqrt(x)) * truncate(sqrt(x)) == x
```

When I loading the function I get the error:

```
Prelude> :load "some.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( some.hs, interpreted )

some.hs:2:13:
    No instance for (RealFrac Int)
      arising from a use of `truncate' at some.hs:2:13-29
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `truncate (sqrt (x))'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely
        `truncate (sqrt (x)) * truncate (sqrt (x))'
    In the expression: truncate (sqrt (x)) * truncate (sqrt (x)) == x

some.hs:2:22:
    No instance for (Floating Int)
      arising from a use of `sqrt' at some.hs:2:22-28
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
    In the first argument of `truncate', namely `(sqrt (x))'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `truncate (sqrt (x))'
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely
        `truncate (sqrt (x)) * truncate (sqrt (x))'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

But if i try to execute:

```
Prelude> truncate(sqrt(9))*truncate(sqrt(9))==9
True
```

all is fine.

Why I get the error and how to fix it ?

Comment: Same reason as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970484/no-instance-for-floating-int

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting the errors because of type mismatches.  The type of `sqrt` is `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`, and the type of `truncate` is `truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`.  The former says that `sqrt` takes as input any floating-point number, and returns one of the same type as output; the latter says it can truncate any real fractional number<sup>1</sup> into any integral number.  However, you assert that `x` is an `Int`, and an `Int` isn't a floating-point number.  Thus, the second error: "No instance for `(Floating Int)` arising from a use of ``sqrt`'".  This says that because of `sqrt x`, it wanted `Int` to be a floating-point number, but there's no definition for that.  Your first error is similar: since `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`, its output is the same as its input, so you're trying to call `truncate` on an integer.  This of course makes no sense, since `Int` is not a `RealFrac`, and that's why you get the first error.  Fixing this is easy:

```
isSquare :: Int -> Bool
isSquare x = let x' = truncate $ sqrt (fromIntegral x :: Double) in x'*x' == x
```

The `fromIntegral` function has the type `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`; it can convert any integral number into *any* number at all.  This is why we need to tell Haskell that we want it to produce a `Double`; it'd default to that anyway, but it's nice to be clear (though not necessary).  `Double` is an instance both of `Floating` and `RealFrac`, so you can `sqrt` and `truncate` it.  I also rearranged your code a little; the way it is up there is how I'd write it, since this way we only compute the `truncation` and `sqrt` once.  Also, note that if you remove the type signature, Haskell will infer the more general type `isSquare :: Integral a => a -> Bool`, since you never assume that `x` is precisely an `Int`.

The reason that `truncate(sqrt(9))*truncate(sqrt(9))==9` successfully returned `True` is because of the type of `9`.  You can ask GHCi to tell you this:

```
Prelude> :t 9
9 :: (Num t) => t
```

In Haskell, all integral numeric literals have the type `Num t => t` (`9.0`, or any number with a decimal point, has the type `Fractional t => t`).  This means that they can be *any* kind of number at all, which is a good thing.  Otherwise, `9` would have to just be an `Int` or `Integer`, and defining new number types—or even using both `Int` and `Integer`!<sup>2</sup>—would be a royal pain.  Thus, when you write `truncate(sqrt(9))`, GHCi determines that `9` must be an instance of `Floating` (from `sqrt`) and `RealFrac` (from `truncate`), which it defaults to `Double`, making everything work.  This defaulting is standard behavior for numeric types (it's why you could leave out the `:: Double` in my definition of `isSquare`), though not for anything else ([except in GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.6/html/users_guide/ch03s04.html#extended-default-rules), which extends it for convenience).  Since `9` isn't just an `Int`, but `x` is, you don't need to convert `9`, but you do need to convert `x`.

---

**1:** The difference between `Floating` and `RealFrac` is that, for instance, `Complex Double` is an instance of `Floating` but not `RealFrac`, and `Rational` is an instance of `RealFrac` but not `Floating`.  `Float` and `Double` are instances of both.

**2:** In case you haven't come across this, the difference is that `Int` is finite-precision, and `Integer` is arbitrary-precision.

Answer (score 3):

You're treating integers as floats. Hence, the types don't match.

Use `fromIntegral`:

```
isSquare :: Int -> Bool
isSquare n = truncate(sqrt(x)) * truncate(sqrt(x)) == n
             where x = fromIntegral n
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all that efficient but a cute way of determining if a number is a square, using integer arithmetic only:

```
isSquare x = x == head (dropWhile (< x) squares)
  where squares = scanl1 (+) [1,3..]
```

Comment: @wnoise: No it doesn't.  Try evaluating `take 10 $ scanl1 (+) [1,3..]` in GHCi – the result is `[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]`.