# Function to Calculate `log` of Integer

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following function.

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f x = if (odd x) then 0 else (floor . logBase 2) x
```

But the following compile-time error occurs:

> F.hs:2:31:
>       No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `floor'
>       Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
>       In the first argument of`(.)', namely `floor'
>       In the expression: floor . logBase 2
>       In the expression: (floor . logBase 2) x
>
> F.hs:2:39:
>       No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of `logBase'
>       Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Integer)
>       In the second argument of`(.)', namely `logBase 2'
>       In the expression: floor . logBase 2
>       In the expression: (floor . logBase 2) x Failed, modules loaded: none.

How can I properly write the above function?

Comment: `fromIntegral` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, luqui. This was particularly helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1970515/409976.

Comment: `floor . logBase 2` => `floor . logBase 2 . fromIntegral`

Comment: Why don't you want to look at odd numbers? logs work on any positive number.

Comment: My mistake for not specifying. I'm working on this homework [problem 5](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf) from 2013 - for self-learning. I should've worded the question better

Answer (score 13):

*This will be a tad long, as I would like to not just give you code that works, but explain the issue in depth so you can understand GHC's type errors better.*

As already answered briefly (and as the type error tries its best to tell you, although it is certainly not clear enough), in order to use `logBase x y`, the two parameters `x` and `y` must both be instances of the "floating point" typeclasses.

In particular, `logBase` is a method of the `Floating` typeclass (from the [Prelude's documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html)):

```
class Fractional a => Floating a where Source
    logBase :: a -> a -> a
```

We also find, also from the Prelude:

```
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where Source
    floor :: Integral b => a -> b
```

That is, in order to use the function `(floor . logBase)`, we need two parameters which are `Fractional` (since `logBase` requires this), and `Real` (since `floor` requires both). The merger of these two is defined as `RealFrac`, and that's exactly what GHC is complaining you failed to provide it (in your function's type declaration).

Why is it complaining? From the Prelude we find the following `instance` declarations for `RealFrac`. Note that "`RealFrac Integer`" is missing:

```
RealFrac Double  
RealFrac Float   
RealFrac CDouble     
RealFrac CFloat  
Integral a => RealFrac (Ratio a)     
HasResolution a => RealFrac (Fixed a)
```

The way Haskell works, is that if you give it an integer literal (consecutive digits without a decimal point), it will assume that it belongs to the `Integral` typeclass (and will try to figure out whether to make it an `Integer` or `Int` implicitly), but it will **never** implicitly promote an integer literal to one of the `Fractional` classes (including `RealFrac`). Since there is no "`RealFrac Integer`" line, this means that you can't expect Haskell to compile your code.

You are telling Haskell that you will give it `Integral` instances by your explicit type declaration (this is one of the reasons why these are generally a good idea -- Haskell would have quietly accepted your function declaration otherwise, only to throw compilation errors in the client functions that use it):

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
```

The solution is to promote your integers by using the following function (which converts `Integral`s into any compatible `Num`ber types):

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

`Floor` performs the conversion in the opposite direction (from `Fractional` to `Integral`), as shown by its type.

**In conclusion** you need to simply say

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f x = if (odd x) then 0 else (floor . logBase 2.0 . fromIntegral) x
```

Note the `fromIntegral` call to make the type of the parameter compatible with what the compiler expects, as well as the use of `2.0` (a `Fractional` literal) for the base.

Comment: Welcome to the Haskell tag on Stack Overflow, and well done for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that `logBase` requires conversion to a `Floating` type, which may lead to erroneous results.

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f x = if (odd x) then 0 else (floor . logBase 2.0 . fromIntegral) x

λ> f (2^99999)
    179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

This happens because `(2^99999 :: Double) = Infinity`, and the `floor Infinity` apparently evaluates to... something surprising.

The [integer-logarithms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-logarithms) package provides an [`integerLog2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-logarithms-1.0.2/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Logarithms.html#v:integerLog2) function which works better:

```
λ> import Math.NumberTheory.Logarithms

λ> integerLog2 (2^99999)
    99999
it :: Int
```

The function in `integer-logarithms` is just a thin wrapper around [integer-gmp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp), so you could also use that directly:

```
λ> :set -XMagicHash

λ> import GHC.Exts

λ> import GHC.Integer.Logarithms

λ> I# (integerLog2# (2^99999))
    99999
it :: Int
```

Note that these functions return a value even if the result is not a power of two:

```
λ> integerLog2 1023
    9
```