# Haskell - From generic to Integer | No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of ‘floor’

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm learning haskell.

I'm trying to solve a problem in which you're given a number (n) and you have to find a pair (m, k) where m^k would make n a perfect power.

> n is a perfect power if there exist natural numbers m > 1, and k > 1
> such that m^k = n.

This is what I came up with so far

```
module Test where

isPerfectPowerOf :: (Floating p, Enum p, RealFrac p) => p -> Maybe [(p, p)]
isPerfectPowerOf i
        | null perfectList = Nothing
        | otherwise = Just perfectList
        where perfectList = filter (\(x, _) -> floor x == x) [(logBase x i, x) | x <- [2 .. (i - 1)]]
```

and it works.
But as you can see, with very generic types. What I want is for it to work with

```
isPerfectPowerOf :: Integer -> Maybe [(Integer, Integer)]
```

So for debugging purposes I placed this signature over the code which gave me these errors

```
severity: 'Error'
message: '    • No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of ‘floor’
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘floor x’
      In the expression: floor x == x
      In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely
        ‘(\ (x, _) -> floor x == x)’

severity: 'Error'
message: '    • No instance for (Floating Integer)
        arising from a use of ‘logBase’
    • In the expression: logBase x i
      In the expression: (logBase x i, x)
      In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely
        ‘[(logBase x i, x) | x <- [2 .. (i - 1)]]’
```

So if I'm not completely off the mark I'll need to somehow typecast floor's and logBase's inputs properly.

> `floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`
>
> `logBase :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`

How should I go about doing it?
Or if it isn't the problem what could be?

Comment: Closely related: [*Function to Calculate \`log\` of Integer*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26416323/2751851) (make sure to also read [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45155332/2751851) there).

Comment: @duplode Ok so if I as an example put i as 5, the code around logBase would look like `[logBase x (5 :: Integer) | x <- [2..10]]` because logBase is expecting floating/fractional, this should fix it `[logBase x (fromIntegral (5 :: Integer)) | x <- [2..10]]`. And it works in ghci but compiler still throws the same error. To be more precise `[((logBase x (fromIntegral (5 :: Integer))), x) | x <- [2..10]]`

Comment: Although that did fix first arg of filter `filter (\(x, _) -> floor (fromIntegral x) == x)`

Comment: It seems you'd still need, at a minimum, to floor the results of `filter`. Also note that `floor (fromIntegral x) == x` will always succeed. Trying to make an useful test out of `floor x == x` forces you to fight against floating-point arithmetic -- while you might manage to work your way around that, you are probably better off with not using floating-point in the first place (eg. by using integer log functions, as the answer I linked to suggests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you tried:

```
perfectList :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
perfectList i = filter (\(x, _) -> floor x == x) [(logBase x i, x) | x <- [2 .. (i - 1)]]
```

(I'm going to deal with `perfectList` here for the sake of brevity. Note, though, that the conversion to `Maybe` in `isPerfectPowerOf` is perhaps redundant, as the nothingness of the `Maybe` result is equivalent to the emptiness of the list.)

That results in the two type errors you quoted. The first one arises because the argument to `floor` must be of some [`RealFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac) type, and `Integral` isn't one of them. Similarly, the second error arises because `logBase` takes and returns values of some [`Floating`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating) type (and so you need to not only convert the arguments to floating-point but also convert the result back to `Integer`). Performing these adjustments results in:

```
perfectList :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
perfectList i = fmap (\(k, x) -> (floor k, x))
    . filter (\(k, _) -> fromIntegral (floor k) == k)
    $ [(logBase (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral i), x) | x <- [2 .. (i - 1)]]
```

(Note that I have renamed your log variable, for the sake of clarity; you might also want to swap the order of the elements in the pairs.)

Since you are using a list comprehension already, it is easier to shift the `fmap` and the `filter` into it:

```
perfectList :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
perfectList i = [(k', x) | x <- [2 .. (i - 1)]
    , let k = logBase (fromIntegral x) (fromIntegral i), let k' = floor k
    , fromIntegral k' == k
    ]
```

On a final note, using `floor` to check whether a floating-point number is "really" a round number isn't fully reliable:

```
GHCi> fromIntegral (floor (logBase 2 (2**29))) == logBase 2 (2**29)
False
```

That being so, an ultimately sounder approach would be switching to an algorithm that finds perfect powers using integer arithmetic throughout, thus avoiding floating-point altogether. (While I suspect you'd want to implement that yourself, for an off-the-shelf solution check the [`Math.NumberTheory.Powers` module from the *arithmoi* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.6.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers.html).)

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering in detail. I did manage to get successful run using integer - log functions as you mentioned in your last comment. This answer clarifies a lot more.