# How to input two integers from command line and return square root of sum of squares

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to start learning Haskell. I want to enter two numbers from the command line and and return the sqrt root of the sum of the square of each number. This is the Pythagorean Theorem

Surely I thought I'd find an example somewhere, so I could wrap my head around taking some input, passing the input to a function, returning it, and printing the result out. Trying to work through this simple case. PHP / Javascript programmer, wanting to learn functional programming, so like I'm learning Martian at this point. Sorry if this question's been asked or is too simple. Surely I'm close, but I don't understand what I'm missing. I understand the sqrt would return a floating point number.

```
module Main where

hypotenuse a b = sqrt $ a * a + b * b
main :: IO ()
main = do
  input1 <- getLine
  input2 <- getLine
  let a = read input1 :: Int
  let b = read input2 :: Int
  print $ hypotenuse a b
```

This returns an error:

> No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘hypotenuse',
>   line 10, character 11

the 'h' in hypotenuse is highlighted in my Atom editor IDE. with the ghc-mod plugin to check.

UPDATE:
@peers answer solved my problem ...

Thanks stackoverflow.com, my first haskell program https://github.com/jackrabbithanna/haskell-pythagorean-theorem

Comment: Where is the function type declaration for your method?

Comment: There is none. Should there be? Starting with the simplest possible and working my way up.

Comment: Iirc there should be one. Like `hypothenuse :: Floating -> Floating -> Floating`

Comment: Using this Atom editor, with several haskell plugins. When I over over it, it shows me: hypotenuse :: Floating a => a -> a -> a  now hypotenuse :: Floating x => x -> x -> x works just as well, however hypothenuse :: Floating -> Floating -> Floating shows an error

Comment: Perhaps there's some syntax issues. Anyway, if you're trying to learn functional programming, calling built-in functions isn't the best way to go about doing it. You want to work with pattern matching, recursion, folds and all. Good luck!

Comment: @peer helped me out good...Thanks everyone. https://github.com/jackrabbithanna/haskell-pythagorean-theorem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No instance for (Floating Int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970484/no-instance-for-floating-int)

Comment: Obviously the question I asked is more than No instance for (Floating int) ... if someone was searching for the question asked in the title, they would get the answer straight away..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sqrt` expects input of type class `Floating` but you provide `Int`s which do not instantiate `Floating`.
In ghci you can see the type signature of `sqrt` with `:t sqrt`. It is `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`.
`Int` implements several type classes as can be seen with `:info Int`:

```
instance Eq Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Ord Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Show Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
instance Read Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Enum Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Num Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Real Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
```

but `Floating` is not among them.
Try `read`ing as `Double` or converting the `Int`s with `fromIntegral`.

Both ways in the code:

```
module Main where

hypotenuse a b = sqrt $ a * a + b * b
main :: IO ()
main = do
  input1 <- getLine
  input2 <- getLine
  let a = read input1 :: Double
  let b = read input2 :: Int
  print $ hypotenuse a (fromIntegral b)
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me figure out my first Haskell program! In high school I wrote an numerical expression evaluator with order of operations and parentheses, in C, with recursion, with 100 lines of code or something . My goal is to reason out the shortest code way to do that in Haskell as a way to learn.

Comment: @jackrabbithanna If that’s your goal, then it may be of use to you to have a look at the `megaparsec` library for parsing, along with [its tutorials](https://markkarpov.com/learn-haskell.html#megaparsec-tutorials). Haskell has lots of libraries for this sort of thing — you’ll almost certainly be able to write that program in <100 lines in Haskell.